# Android Place Picker restricted area (city boundary) library

Tags: android, google-places-api, picker, boundary

I'm looking for some library similar to [Google PlacePicker](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker), but I also need some additional features:

- City boundary should be possible to be shown on map (provided as
  geojson)
- It should not be possible to choose place/location outside city boundary

As far as I know, Google Place Picker does not allow to do that. Do you know any open source library that allows to do what I need? It's pretty easy to implement, however it needs some coding, so any ready for use library is really welcome.